# Connecting my React Application to my Springboot API (Post)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I'm getting an **Axios Network Error when trying to upload a file** to my endpoint using my app, and the `App.js` re-renders upon every attempt. This is then sent to `mongodb`.

**The error:**

```bash
network error
AxiosError:Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52506:14)
```

**My API call (react):**

```js
import api from "../../api/axiosConfig";
//my axios import which contains base url + headers

const uploadHandler = async () => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  if (!image) {
    console.log('No file selected');
    return;
  }
  try {
    formData.append('image', image);
    for (const value of formData.values()) {
      console.log(value);
    }
    const response = api.post('/photos/add/' + employeeEmail + '/' + month + '/' + year, formData);
    //api here is the base url
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

**My axios config file**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
    headers: {"ngrok-skip-browser-warning": "true"}
});
```

**My Controller:**

```java
@Autowired
PhotoService photoService;

@PostMapping("/photos/add/{employeeEmail}/{month}/{year}")
public ResponseEntity<Photo> addPhoto(@PathVariable("employeeEmail") String employeeEmail, @PathVariable String month, @PathVariable String year, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
  return new ResponseEntity<Photo>(photoService.addPhoto(employeeEmail, month, year, image), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I've tried following many tutorials and their formatting of how the url is called/formData is sent and I'm very very new to react so I'd like some help understanding where I made a mistake.

Comment: Could it be because you're missing a `/` between `'/photos/add'` and `employeeEmail`?

Comment: If you get a network error, it would be very helpful if you could share more information about the error (a screenshot of the devtools, ...). In addition it would be nice if you could simplify your code further so there aren't unknown variables for us (eg. provide a dummy `employeeEmail`, `month` and `year`).

Comment: I fixed the question adding in what you saw Phil, and included the error message I've been getting in the browser as well. I've ruled out possible errors with the API by using postman and from the file upload function of my app by logging the formData values, I'm thinking it might be the api call that's giving me problems but I can't find any help online so far.

Answer (score -1):

Your error occurs because you miss give some variable when you send it to Spring,
and I don't know if you use axios instead of api.post but you should use it

```
let reqInstance = axios.create({
headers: {
  Authorization : 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)
//   Authorization : `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("accessToken")}`
  },
'Content-Type': 'application/json',  });

   getAll(url) {
    return reqInstance.get(API_BASE_URL + url);
}
```

Comment: I added how I use axios within the project. I haven't seen the approach you suggested but as I understand its already pretty similar.